# How to train model for profit and not accuracy?

Tags: neural-networks, modeling

I have a modelling problem that I'm not sure how to approach.

Lets say I have a bunch of sports data, for example some stats on 1000 football games. I'm using a regular old feedforward neural net to train a model to classify the likelihood of each outcome, home / draw / away. Then I want to know if, were I to bet on outcomes that have better bookmaker's odds than the probability implies, over time would it be a profitable strategy?

My problem is that when training the neural net, it is training for "accuracy", which means it is always trying to fit the outcomes to 1/0/0, 0/1/0 or 0/0/1 (depending on what the true result was for each row) rather than being happy with a, for example, 0.8/0.1/0.1 where the third result was what actually happened but had 50:1 odds at the bookies.

Apart from setting up a separate "test" scenario that applies the odds and calculates profit after each epoch, and then hacking around with different parameters of the net until I randomly come across a profitable combination, is there a way I can model my data so that the net is actually targeting profitability instead of accuracy?

Apologies if I haven't explained it very well, please let me know and I can clarify!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can applying reinforcement learning by simply changing the loss function.

If the output of your network is 0.8/0.1/0.1 then treat this as if you are betting \$0.8 on home, \$0.1 on a draw, and \$0.1 on away.

If I understand odds correctly then a 50:1 odds means that you get \$51 back if you bet \$1. Therefore, if you bet \$0.1 then the money you get back is $(0.1\times 51 \times \text{[result]})$; where [result] is 0 if this option didn't win and 1 if the option did win.

Suppose in your example the odds are 2:1 for home, 3:1 for a draw, and 50:1 for away. And suppose that the result was that "away" won. The profit would be:

$\text{profit}=(0.8 \times 3 \times 0) + (0.1 \times 4 \times 0) + (0.1 \times 51 \times 1) - 1$

I would recommend adding a fourth option of betting on nothing, then if your network output was 0.8/0.1/0.08/0.02 for home/draw/away/nothing the profit is:

$\text{profit}=(0.8 \times 3 \times 0) + (0.1 \times 4 \times 0) + (0.08 \times 51 \times 1) + (0.02) - 1$

The loss function is just the negative of the profit

$\text{Loss}=1- (0.8 \times 3 \times 0) - (0.1 \times 4 \times 0) - (0.08 \times 51 \times 1) - (0.02)$

Take derivatives of this loss function to train your network by gradient descent as your normally would.

Edit:

To get the partial derivatives of this loss function lets first define it symbolically.

We have the odds offered for home, draw, and away; call these $o_1, o_2, o_3$. There is also the odds for the "none" option I mentioned, call this $o_4$. If you bet £1 on "none" you always get back £1, therefore the odds for the "none" option is always $o_4=1$

You must have collected data on the results. Call the home/draw/away results $r_1, r_2, r_3$, the result is $1$ if it happened or $0$ if it didn't. If away wins the game then $r_3=1$ and $r_2=r_1=0$. The result for "none" is always $r_4=1$.

Lastly, suppose your model outputs $z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4$, these figures are then put through the softmax function to give the amounts of money gambled $x_1,x_2, x_3, x_4$.

Where $x_j = \frac{e^{z_j}}{\sum_{i=1}^4 e^{z_i}}$

The loss is defined as

$$L=1-\sum_{i=1}^4 x_i o_i r_i$$

You want to get the partial derivative $\frac{\partial L}{\partial z_j}$. Once you have this the rest of the derivatives with respect to the model parameters works like a normal neural net.

Apply the chain rule:

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial z_j} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial x_j} \times \frac{\partial x_j}{\partial z_j}$$

You can see easily that $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_j}$ = $-o_jr_j$

To get $\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial z_j}$ look at the softmax function.

$\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial z_j} = \frac{e^{z_j}((\sum_{k=1}^4 e^{z_k})-e^{z_j})}{(\sum_{k=1}^4 e^{z_k})^2}$

Therefore $\frac{\partial L}{\partial z_j} = -o_jr_j \frac{e^{z_j}((\sum_{k=1}^4 e^{z_k})-e^{z_j})}{(\sum_{k=1}^4 e^{z_k})^2}$

You can proceed to get the derivatives with respect to weights in the model using the normal approach for neural networks.

Notice how the derivative and the loss depends on $o_jr_j$ only instead of $o_j$ and $r_j$ separately. Consider storing your data as $o_jr_j$ rather than storing odds and results separately.

Comment: I was so focused on trying to model my data so that the net would give me what I needed, I didn't even think about changing the loss function itself! Thanks!!

Comment: I think I've made a mistake in my maths - could you give me a hint as to what the partial derivative of this function would be? I was trying to combine this with multi-class cross entropy - is that a bad idea?

Comment: @Matt Using cross entropy as the loss makes the derivative of the softmax function easier to get. It will be more complicated to get the derivative using the loss I defined above but it does not make sense to use cross entropy. You're trying to minimise financial loss, cross entropy only makes sense as a way to measure predictive power.

Comment: @Matt I've edited to derive the partial derivative

Comment: I can see where I went wrong - you're a legend!

Comment: I am having an issue with my network, am I right in thinking that at break-even point (profit = 0) the gradient will be 0 and it will stop learning? Is there a hack I can add to the partial derivatives to get the gradient=0 point to be a significantly negative loss?

Comment: @Matt gradient descent will work to minimise the loss function, if your training works well then this will cause the loss to become negative (i.e. profit)